# C++: Boost cpp_dec_float Independent?

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point-precision, arbitrary-precision

I just downloaded Boost because I need the precise floating-point arithmetic found in `cpp_dec_float.hpp`; I looked around a lot for other options, and couldn't find a good alternative.

I spent a while figuring out how to install `bcp`, and now I've finally installed all of it. I ran `bcp` to copy the `cpp_dec_float.hpp` file into my project, and lo and behold! Now I have a 9.5 MB Boost folder sitting in my C++ application directory. This will not be acceptable for my purposes.

Is there a way I can only install `cpp_dec_float` library without the rest of the `multiprecision` part? If not, does anyone know of a **lightweight** (VERY important!), fast, **maintained** and (at least relatively) **recent** library for arbitrary-precision numbers?

Comment: Don't know what your "lightweight" requirement is exactly, but did you try MPFR?

Comment: Interesting... Somehow I overlooked it. Will look into it. (possibly MPFR C++, as I'm going for a more object-oriented approach, and it looks like the most maintained one so far - haven't looked at it much though).

Answer (score 0):

You can download Boost not to your application directory. Usually you install Boost for use with all projects by all users. Boost.Multiprecision is a header-only library, you only need its headers.

If you need to reduce your space that much, you can try to do the following (I did not test it).

Follow standard steps from Boost installation:

1. Download Boost sources, say, to folder my_boost
2. cd my_boost; mkdir build
3. Run ./bootstrap (will create a bjam executable for your platform)

Then ask Boost to configure for specific set of libraries only. Since the library multiprecision depends on some others, you might need to specify them all:

1. bjam --build-dir=build **--with-multiprecicsion** --with-utility --with-type_traits install

You are guaranteed that unrelated libraries will not be built. I am not so sure that unrelated header files will not be copied to Boost include library.

See "bjam --help" for more options.

Comment: How is this different from `bcp`? Supposedly it only builds required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

i've also noticed that bcp copies more files than it should.  my strategy:  get it compiling, then spend 10 minutes removing stuff from your boost dir, checking to see if it still compiles each time.  :)